# DIV at 100% height, containing Table, Scrollbars wanted, not shown

Tags: html, layout

Goal:

- I want a container div to be 100% of the height available to it in the browser.
- The div contains a table, that has many records. So many, that it extends well below the bottom of the visible window available to the div.
- When the table is displayed in the div, the div must not extend it's height below the visible window, but instead, stay at 100% of what is available in the visible window, and create a scrollbar, so the user must scroll down using the scrollbar in the div, and not the scrollbar of the page.

All solutions I could find involve setting a fixed height of the containing div.  But that is going to cause problems for people with small screens on tablets, and it's going to look dumb on large full sized PC monitors.  I need the containing div to be set at a height of 100%, so that it will expand and shrink according to what the user does with the browser, and I need a vertical scrollbar on that same div, not a scrollbar on the whole webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option, you can use media parameters for different screen size, but it will take too long to modify size for every of the world monitor, so I would try to use specific values like "vh" in CSS styles that will give to container a fixed size to the USER's screen

Comment: Wow.  Olek for the win!  Thank you.  Here is the solution: (I just took a wild guess, using 80)
<div style="height:80vh; overflow-y: scroll;">
<... very long table>
</div>